# How to declare STL style C++ hash map iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

Here's my HashMap example in C++14:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <class K, class V> class MyNode {
public:
  std::pair<const K, V> value;
};

template <class K, class V, class NodePtr> class MyIterator {
public:
  MyIterator(NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ~MyIterator() = default;
  MyIterator(const MyIterator &) = default;
  MyIterator &operator=(const MyIterator &) = default;

  std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() { return node_->value; }
  const std::pair<const K, V> &operator*() const { return node_->value; }
  std::pair<const K, V> *&operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
  const std::pair<const K, V> *operator->() const { return &(node_->value); }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &operator++() { return *this; }
  MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> operator++(int) { return *this; }

  bool operator==(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ == other.node_;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator<K, V, NodePtr> &other) {
    return node_ != other.node_;
  }

private:
  NodePtr node_;
};

template <class K, class V> class MyHashMap {
public:
  using Iterator = MyIterator<K, V, MyNode<K, V> *>;
  using ConstIterator = MyIterator<K, V, const MyNode<K, V> *>;

  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator begin() const { return ConstIterator(&node); }
  ConstIterator cbegin() const { return ConstIterator(&node); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator end() const { return ConstIterator(nullptr); }
  ConstIterator cend() const { return ConstIterator(nullptr); }

  MyNode<K, V> node;
};

void test(const int &a) {}

int main(void) {
  MyHashMap<int, int> hm;
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.cbegin(); i != hm.cend();
       i++) {
    test(i->second);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile by: `clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o main.exe`

Which give me:

```
main.cpp:53:43: error: no viable conversion from 'MyIterator<[2 * ...], MyNode<int, int> *>' to 'MyIterator<[2 * ...], const MyNode<int, int> *>'
  for (MyHashMap<int, int>::ConstIterator i = hm.begin(); i != hm.end(); i++) {
                                          ^   ~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:11:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'MyHashMap<int, int>::Iterator' (aka 'MyIterator<int, int, MyNode<int, int> *>') to 'const MyNode<int, int> *' for 1st
      argument
  MyIterator(NodePtr node = nullptr) : node_(node) {}
  ^
main.cpp:13:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'MyHashMap<int, int>::Iterator' (aka 'MyIterator<int, int, MyNode<int, int> *>') to
      'const MyIterator<int, int, const MyNode<int, int> *> &' for 1st argument
  MyIterator(const MyIterator &) = default;
  ^
main.cpp:18:49: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::pair<const int, int> *' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'const std::pair<const int, int> *'
  std::pair<const K, V> *&operator->() { return &(node_->value); }
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:58:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'MyIterator<int, int, const MyNode<int, int> *>::operator->' requested here
    test(i->second);
          ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: About your iterator, you can start by checking `std::iterator_traits<MyIterator<...>>` contains all of its member types (spoiler, it does not ;). See [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

Answer (score 0):

> Is my HashMap and Iterator declaration correct ?

You have your `using`s the wrong way round.

You don't have any `Node<K, const V>`s to make pointers to.

To conform to [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container), you should spell it `iterator` and `const_iterator`, and provide the other `using`s

You either need to specialise [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), or provide the definitions it requires.

```
template <class K, class V>
class MyHashMap {
public:
  using iterator = MyIterator<K, V, Node<K, V>>;
  using const_iterator = MyIterator<K, V, const Node<K, V>> = ConstIterator;

  iterator begin();
  const_iterator begin() const;
  iterator end();
  const_iterator end() const;
};
```

Comment: why using `const_iterator = MyIterator<K, V, const Node<K, V>>` instead of `const_iterator = MyIterator<K, V, Node<K, const V>>` ?

Comment: You don't have any `Node<K, const V>` objects. There isn't a valid conversion from `const Node<K, V> *` to `Node<K, const V> *`

Comment: I think map const_iterator in C++ STL library is using `const_iterator = MapIterator<K, V, Node<K, const V>*>`, not `const_iterator = MapIterator<K, V, const Node<K, V>*>`.

Comment: I don't know where you are looking, by my implementation has `typedef _Tree_const_iterator<_Tree_val<_Val_types> > const_iterator; typedef _Tree_iterator<_Tree_val<_Val_types> > iterator;`

Comment: Would you please show me you source code which contains `_Tree_const_iterator` ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015's <xtree>

Comment: Well, I remembered I read part of gcc source code which implement the `const_iterator`, it declares `const V` since the `value` part should never been modified in `const_iterator`, not declare the whole `const std::pair<const K, V>` or `const Node<K, V>`. But gcc source code is too large to understand.

Comment: GCC's implementation of the standard library can rely on undefined and implementation-defined behaviours doing a particular thing, because it's part of the implementation. You shouldn't do that in your code.

Comment: I've updated the minimum example, would you please check it again?

Comment: You should probably have a converting constructor in `ConstIterator` that takes an `Iterator`. It's not a good idea to try to squeeze them into one template

Comment: should I define the ConstIterator like: template<class K, class V, class ConstNodePtr> ConstIterator, which contains a const NodePtr ?